# Comparing large strings with percentage differnce in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to compare a large string of text with another large string of text in another cell and get percentage string match ignoring case sensativity.

For example:

Cell a1: Please support this application inquiry

Cell b2: Please support another application process

do comparison of both cells and return percentage match: %60 match with possibility of highlighting.

Thanks

I tried column match.

```
Function CompareString(rngS1 As Range, rngS2 As Range, strType As String, Optional boolCase As Boolean = True) As Variant
Dim vW1, vW2
Dim oDic As Object
Dim lngW As Long, lngU As Long, lngM As Long, lngTemp As Long, rngCell As Range
Dim strTemp As String, strC As String, strB As String
vW2 = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(rngS2.Text, ".", ""), Chr(100), " ")), " ")
Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For lngW = LBound(vW2) To UBound(vW2) Step 1
    strTemp = vW2(lngW)
    With oDic
        If Not .exists(strTemp) Then
            lngU = lngU + 1
            .Add strTemp, lngU
        End If
    End With
Next lngW
Set oDic = Nothing
For Each rngCell In rngS1.Cells
    strC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(Replace(rngCell.Text, ".", ""), Chr(100), " "))
    If strC <> "" Then
        If strC = rngS2.Text Then
            lngM = lngU
            strB = rngS2.Text
        Else
            vW1 = Split(strC, " ")
            lngTemp = 0
            For lngW = LBound(vW2) To UBound(vW2) Step 1
                strTemp = vW2(lngW)
                If boolCase Then
                    lngTemp = lngTemp + rngS1.Parent.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND("" " & strTemp & " "","" " & strC & " "")))")
                Else
                    lngTemp = lngTemp - IsNumeric(Application.Match(strTemp, vW1, 0))
                End If
            Next lngW
            If lngTemp > lngM Then
                lngM = lngTemp
                strB = rngCell.Text
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell
Select Case UCase(strType)
    Case "P"
        CompareString = lngM / lngU
    Case "S"
        CompareString = strB
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to write a [user defined function (UDF)](https://www.vertex42.com/blog/excel-formulas/custom-user-defined-functions.html) in VBA code to accomplish exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this involves deeper machine learning which excel formula is not capable of. For instance, `This inquiry supports PLEASE Application` would probably give you close to 100% match to Cell a1 if using excel/VBA to do the comparison, but the logic and implied meaning of each sentence are quite different. Will 100% match be misleading in this case? It all depends on the purpose of finding the matches and what you try to deliver from the finding.

Comment: What is the purpose of this comparison and how are you defining the difference?  There is a lot written concerning `edit distance` and it is not clear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Im trying to compare two large strings on different cells and find the percentage match compared to each other.  Terry yes i want it to give %60 match from the above examples not %100.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple but should give you what you're looking for. It splits the strings in the cells up based on spaces and should return the overlap of words within them as a percent.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox 100 * CompareTwoStrings(Range("A1").Value2, Range("B2").Value2)
End Sub

Function CompareTwoStrings(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As Double

    str1 = ReplaceSpecialChars(str1)
    str2 = ReplaceSpecialChars(str2)

    Dim splitStrShorter As Variant
    Dim splitStrLonger As Variant

    If (Len(str1) - Len(Replace(str1, " ", ""))) > (Len(str2) - Len(Replace(str2, " ", ""))) Then
        splitStrLonger = Split(LCase(str1), " ")
        splitStrShorter = Split(LCase(str2), " ")
    Else
        splitStrLonger = Split(LCase(str2), " ")
        splitStrShorter = Split(LCase(str1), " ")
    End If

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(splitStrLonger)
        If Not dict.exists(splitStrLonger(i)) Then
            dict.Add splitStrLonger(i), ""
        End If
    Next i

    Dim frequency As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(splitStrShorter)
        If dict.exists(splitStrShorter(i)) Then
            frequency = frequency + 1
        End If
    Next i

    CompareTwoStrings = frequency / (UBound(splitStrLonger) + 1)

End Function

Function ReplaceSpecialChars(ByVal strToReplace As String) As String

    Dim specialChars As String
    specialChars = "`,-,=,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,+,[,],\,{,},|,;,',:," & Chr(34) & ",.,/,<,>,?"

    Dim char As Variant
    For Each char In Split(specialChars, ",")
        strToReplace = Replace(strToReplace, char, "")
    Next

    ReplaceSpecialChars = strToReplace

End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time and effort. I put code into VBA and attached to a button. However i only get a 83.333 match for string with same values in both cells. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Would you mind commenting the two strings here so I can think about it?

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. Appreciate it.                                         So i i used the string "This is a test for the string test" into cell A1 and B2 and got 0.875 match (Should of been a 1.0 match as its the same string for both cells)  Also if i add additional string to which i just mentioned it gives a runtime error 457 so it seems to be limited to number of words and characters?

Comment: oops, I made a disappointingly simple mistake on the number of iterations, so now it should work! I also forgot that `dict` would error out if a word shows up twice in a sentence so I had to check if the word already exists first (this was causing error 457)

Comment: I also added a helper function to remove special characters so that it can better focus on words

Comment: Thanks looks brilliant. I did spot something for example if you put in cell a1: Stakeholder and b2: Stakeholders it will come up with a zero match because of the S in cell b2. Can this be fixed? Also can the text be highlighted to show the match by any chance?  I tried to use code (see opening post now posted) but yours seems better.

Comment: The first question would be a significant enough change that it would probably deserve its own new question. "Fuzzy lookup" might be the answer, i'd research it